# Rails tons of call to action, data lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to know which is the best strategy to approach this situation, let's suppose I have this action:

```
class BetsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @bet = Bet.new(params[:bet])
    # some other operation
  end
end
```

and sometimes I receive tons of call to this action and I could lost data, should I spawn a thread each time? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm surprised you have ANY data saved since this action seems to do no saving! just creating a new object is not equal to saving.

Comment: saving action is not the point, of course i'm going to save the object after #some other operation

Comment: Please try to narrow the scope of your question by providing more details on the rails action. davidrac's answer should provide some guidance to narrow the focus. As it stands, your questions is vague, and it's hard to know under what circumstances it should be considered to be "answered".

Answer (score 0):

Scaling is quite a bit topic and providing an answer that will be exactly right for your needs is not really possible.

But just to get you started:

- In case the action itself takes long to execute then you should
  consider doing some offline work - essentially you should save the
  information you need and have some offline worker run over all the
  queues requests and process them one at a time. This  approach may
  require some redesign of your application. You should consider how
  users get feedback on their actions in case they may fail or in case
  they return some result.
- If the actions are very short and this is just a matter of load, then you should consider other approaches to scaling - additional servers w/ load balancing and such.

I know this is far from complete answer but this is a really large topic...

Comment: thanks, I can use delayed_job or similar, because the action is very short, I'll dig on this topic. thank you